# how to add uneditable url to facebook post using SLComposeViewController in ios 6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

using the socialframework in ios6 if one tries to add an image to the facebook post the added URL gets editable. the URL appears in editable text area.  if no image added then the URL remain uneditable.

```
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
       mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
       mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
       [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iOS 6 %@ integration test!",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]];
       [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
       [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.StackOverflow.com/"]];
       [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

what i want is to have the url and image be uneditable in the post. while user still can type extra text. any idea how to do that?

Comment: did you read my post? let me repeat it. i tried to add url to the facebook sheet without image. that works great, meaning you cannot edit the url in the sheet. but as soon as adding an image to the sheet, the url appears in the editable area. so i want to have the url uneditable. if you ask for the code, please refer to the original post.and i look into slcomposerviewcontroller. there is nothing which could let overriding or work around.

Answer (score 3):

As a part of the `Social.framework`, you cannot make the text uneditable for the user for some security concerns.  All you can provide is a basis on what the user could post, as you have done.  If your app is good enough, the user might choose to post what you have written.  If it is important to you, you might want to look into [Facebook's API](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/), however I cannot help with that.